# IntelliJ IDEA shows error for Jersey quick start in web.xml

Tags: servlets, intellij-idea, jersey, jersey-2.0, maven-archetype

I created a webapp using the maven archetype for Jersey 2.27 quick start, but IntelliJ IDEA show the following error:

> Error:(7, 24) 'org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer' is not assignable to 'javax.servlet.Servlet'

This is the generated web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.myaddress</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you can you run the application successfully then it looks like this bug: [IDEA-86833](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-86833). If it is reproducible in a sample project, please attach it to [IDEA-86833](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-86833)

Comment: Yes, it runs nicely, I will send it, thanks.